Unable to set the Google Play Console Payment Profile: "Uh oh. There was a problem. You don't have permission to complete this action [OR-AC-02]"
I'm the account owner of my Google Play Console Account. I need to change the payment settings, but I'm unable to access it:
"Uh oh. There was a problem.
You don't have permission to complete this action [OR-AC-02]"

App store questions are off-topic here, even if they're intended to be self-answered.

For everyone who has the error code "OR-AC-02": You can find on the Google Cloud troubleshooting page that it stands for the following:

Contact your payments admin to request access to the payment profile. By default, the payments admin is the person who initially created the payment profile.

My issue was the following: The Google Account that owns the Play Console account wasn't part of the payment users in the Google Cloud console. I did the following steps to fix it:

Open the Google Cloud Console
Go to "Billing"
Scroll down to "Manage payment users"
Click "Add new user"
Enter the email address of the Google Play Console account owner account
Set "Admin with all permissions"

